# _debugInitializedType == null': is not true thrown and ios app stuck on splashscreen while running via Patrol

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, flutter-integration-test, flutter-patrol

Running e2e test via patrol for a flutter written app.

Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 149 pos 12: '_debugInitializedType == null': is not true.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the call to `IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`. Patrol has its own binding and you mustn't interfere with it.

---

**EDIT** How are you running your tests? I'm pretty sure you're using `flutter test integration_test`, which does not work. You must run tests with Patrol CLI.

`https://patrol.leancode.co` to learn how to use Patrol.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am running my tests with Patrol CLI but I am getting error while debugging the tests and this error which I am getting is in `package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart` which is in flutter sdk. Thanks